# unknown command 'sql'

Tags: python, django

```
$ ./manage.py sql addressbook                                                                                             
Unknown command: 'sql'
```

I'm trying to look at the SQL generated by an app's models when I get this weird error.

my settings.py

```
import os
# Django settings for DoneBox project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('Levi Campbell', 'levicc00123@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'levicc00123_cc51',
        'USER': 'levicc00123_cc51',
        'PASSWORD': 'n440844291',
        'HOST': 'mysql0.db.koding.com',
        'PORT': 3306,
        }
    }
# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = 'd1eyn4cjl5vzx0.cloudfront.net'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = 'd280kzug7l5rug.cloudfront.net'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '2vhexv#0!u4eeyai9jluz8g&amp;h7=815op$8nwa)5+=2m$hl61cu'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DoneBox.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DoneBox.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps'
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'main',
    'basic.blog',
    'contact_form',
    'django-registration',
    'django-ses',
    'django-storages',
    'dajax',
    'dajaxice',
    'addressbook',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admin'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            }
        }
    }

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 2
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<snip>'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ='<snip>'
STATIC_FILES_BUCKET = "donebox-static"
MEDIA_FILES_BUCKET = "donebox-media"
```

and my requirements.txt:

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.4.3
MySQL-python==1.2.4
argparse==1.2.1
boto==2.7.0
distribute==0.6.34
django-dajax==0.9.2
django-dajaxice==0.5.4.1
django-piston==0.2.3
django-registration==0.8
django-ses==0.4.1
django-storages==1.1.6
django-tagging==0.3.1
markup==0.2
python-dateutil==2.1
six==1.2.0
tweepy==1.13
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

UPDATE: ./manage.py --help now give me a stacktrace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_comma
nd_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 380, in execute
    sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + '\n')
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 231, in main_help_text
    for name, app in get_commands().iteritems():
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/DoneBox/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
```

Does anyone have some idea that might shed some light on this odd problem? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Looks like you've got a problem in your `settings.py` file.  Your database name is configured from `os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME']` but `RDS_DB_NAME` isn't in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

you should have both `sqlall` and `sql` management commands. Both have existed since 1.0, [it appears](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/django-admin/#sql-appname-appname)

```
$ ./manage.py help sqlall
...
Usage: manage.py sqlall [options] <appname appname ...>

Prints the CREATE TABLE, custom SQL and CREATE INDEX SQL statements
for the given model module name(s).
...
```

see the commands which have `sql` in them:

```
$ ./manage.py --help | grep sql
monitor (pid=16660): Starting change monitor.
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlreset
    sqlsequencereset
    sqlcreate
    sqldiff
```

what version of django are you using? -- not that it should matter

```
$ ./manage.py shell
monitor (pid=16669): Starting change monitor.
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 15 2013, 12:25:59) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 3, 'final', 0)
```

As pointed out in a comment, you have a KeyError:

```
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/DoneBox/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
  File "/Users/levicc00123/DoneBox/env/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
```

To get around this, you could use the `get` method of `os.environ` and supply a default value. eg:

```
os.environ.get('RDS_DB_NAME', "default value if not in environment")
```